# Android ActionBar has border when using Nine-Patch background

Tags: android, android-theme, nine-patch

I'm using a nine-patch png as the windowBackground for an Android app. However, I get a 1px border around the ActionBar. This doesn't happen when I use a simple png.

To test this, I've created a basic app using the wizard:

- android:minSdkVersion="10"
- android:targetSdkVersion="17"
- Tested on Galaxy Nexus v.4.2.2

Interestingly enough, the XML Layout preview in Eclipse is showing the same border.

/res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/test4</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Two screenshots comparing the affect (no, this isn't a real background, just one for testing :-) As you can see, the ActionBar is inset by 1px all the way around.

Added - I've tried a manually created 9patch and one using Google's draw9patch tool.

[image: Using the 9-patch background]
[image: Using simple png as background]
[image: The 9-patch png]

Comment: check the color on the outer boundary of your 9patch... it looks like its not full black (#000000)..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar - I've just checked in the GIMP, there's only one unique colour in the outer boundary (and it's #000000). Worth checking though.

Comment: can you post the 9patch file?...

Comment: The 3rd image I've posted is the 9patch - If you rename it to test.9.png the draw9patch tool will open it (I've just downloaded it to make sure, as well as counting the colours in the GIMP again)

Comment: Bah. I've just realised what I was doing wrong. I had *incorrectly* thought that padding (right and bottom) should be exclusive of the stretchable section. By changing the right and bottom borders to be all black (except the corners) has fixed it.